# How to get back to fragment from nested recycler view child adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, view

In my kotlin project, from main activity, one fragment(peoplenearby fragment) is added from bottom menu. In that fragment through nested recycler views profiles images and names viewed. If profle image is clicked, it opens another fragment(ProfileviewPeople) then if back button is pressed in android phone, it goes to main activity. I needs to get back to peoplenearby  fragment page from profileviewpeople. I have added ChildAdapter code, from ChildAdapter i have clicked profileviewpeople fragment instance.   i HAVE ADDED PEOPLENEARBY FRAGMENT PASSING ARRAYLIST CODE, PARENT ADAPTER AND CHILD ADAPTER CODES

```
private fun loadAndDisplayProfile(uid: Int, cntxt: Context) {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putInt("userId", uid)
    val fragment = ProfileViewPeople.newInstance(uid).apply {
        arguments = bundle
    }
    val appCompatActivity = cntx as AppCompatActivity
    appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations( R.anim.slide_in_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right )
        .add(R.id.peopleNearBy, fragment).addToBackStack("selectx")
        .commit()

    Log.d("ChildAdapter", " backStackEntryCount "+appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount)
}
```

FULL CODE:

```java
class ChildAdapter(private val 

myChildList:MutableList<Peoples>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAdapter.ChildHolder>() {   

 class ChildHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
{
        val title1:TextView
        val title2:TextView
        val title3:TextView
        val title4:TextView
        val title5:TextView
        val title6:TextView
        val title7:TextView
        val title8:TextView
        val title9:TextView
        val title10:TextView
        val title11:TextView
        val title12:TextView
        val img1:ImageView
        val img2:ImageView
        val img3:ImageView
        val img4:ImageView
        val img5:ImageView
        val img6:ImageView
        val img7:ImageView
        val img8:ImageView
        val img9:ImageView
        val img10:ImageView
        val img11:ImageView
        val img12:ImageView
        init {
            title1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title1)
            title2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title2)
            title3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title3)
            title4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title4)
            title5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title5)
            title6 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title6)
            title7 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title7)
            title8 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title8)
            title9 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title9)
            title10 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title10)
            title11 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title11)
            title12 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_title12)
            img1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img1)
            img2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img2)
            img3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img3)
            img4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img4)
            img5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img5)
            img6 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img6)
            img7 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img7)
            img8 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img8)
            img9 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img9)
            img10 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img10)
            img11 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img11)
            img12 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_img12)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChildHolder {
        val mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.child_item, parent, false)
        return ChildHolder(mView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChildHolder, position: Int) {
        val title1 = myChildList[position].title1
        holder.title1.text = if (title1.length>10){
            title1.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title1
        }
        val title2 = myChildList[position].title2
        holder.title2.text = if (title2.length>10){
            title2.substring(1,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title2
        }
        val title3 = myChildList[position].title3
        holder.title3.text= if (title3.length>10){
            title3.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title3
        }
        val title4 = myChildList[position].title4
        holder.title4.text = if (title4.length>10){
            title4.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else {
            title4
        }
        val title5 = myChildList[position].title5
        holder.title5.text = if (title5.length>10){
            title5.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title5
        }

        val title6 = myChildList[position].title6
        holder.title6.text = if (title6.length>10){
            title6.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title6
        }
        val title7=myChildList[position].title7
        holder.title7.text = if (title7.length>10){
            title7.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title7
        }
        val title8=myChildList[position].title8
        holder.title8.text = if (title8.length>10){
            title8.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title8
        }
        val title9=myChildList[position].title9
        holder.title9.text = if (title9.length>10){
            title9.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title9
        }
        val title10=myChildList[position].title10
        holder.title10.text = if (title10.length>10){
            title10.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title10
        }
        val title11=myChildList[position].title11
        holder.title11.text = if (title11.length>10){
            title11.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title11
        }
        val title12 =myChildList[position].title12
        holder.title12.text = if (title12.length>10){
            title12.substring(0,10)+"..."
        }else{
            title12
        }

        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img1, holder.img1)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img2, holder.img2)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img3, holder.img3)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img4, holder.img4)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img5, holder.img5)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img6, holder.img6)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img7, holder.img7)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img8, holder.img8)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img9, holder.img9)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img10, holder.img10)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img11, holder.img11)
        loadAndDisplayImage(myChildList[position].img12, holder.img12)

        holder.img1.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid1, holder.img1.context)
        }

        holder.img2.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid2, holder.img2.context)
        }

        holder.img3.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid3, holder.img3.context)
        }

        holder.img4.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid4, holder.img4.context)
        }

        holder.img5.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid5, holder.img5.context)
        }

        holder.img6.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid6, holder.img6.context)
        }

        holder.img7.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid7, holder.img7.context)
        }

        holder.img8.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid8, holder.img8.context)
        }

        holder.img9.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid9, holder.img9.context)
        }

        holder.img10.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid10, holder.img10.context)
        }

        holder.img11.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid11, holder.img11.context)
        }

        holder.img12.setOnClickListener {
            loadAndDisplayProfile(myChildList[position].userid12, holder.img12.context)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myChildList.size
    }

    private fun loadAndDisplayImage(imageUrl: String, imageView: ImageView) {
        if (imageUrl.isNotEmpty()) {
            try {
                Glide.with(imageView.context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.male_avatar)
                    .circleCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageView)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace() // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the loading process
            }
        } else {           
            Glide.get(imageView.context).clearDiskCache()
        }
    }

    private fun loadAndDisplayProfile(uid: Int, cntxt: Context) {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("userId", uid)
        val fragment = ProfileViewPeople.newInstance(uid).apply {
            arguments = bundle
        }
        val appCompatActivity = cntxt as AppCompatActivity
        appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations( R.anim.slide_in_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right )
            .replace(R.id.peopleNearBy, fragment).addToBackStack("selectx")
            .commit()
    }
}
```

PARENT ADAPTER:

```java
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class ParentAdapter(private val context: Context, var parentList:ArrayList<PeopleNearByModelClass>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentAdapter.ParentHolder>() {
    private lateinit var childAdapter:ChildAdapter

    class ParentHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        //val title:TextView
        val mRecyclerView:RecyclerView
        init {
            //title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_title)
            mRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_recyclerview)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ParentHolder {
        val mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.parent_item, parent, false)
        return ParentHolder(mView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentHolder, position: Int) {     

        childAdapter = ChildAdapter(parentList[position].movieList)
        holder.mRecyclerView.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        holder.mRecyclerView.adapter = childAdapter


        if ( position == 0) {
            val template =
                holder.itemView.findViewById<TemplateView>(R.id.my_template)
            template.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        else if (size == position) {
            val template =
                holder.itemView.findViewById<TemplateView>(R.id.my_template)
            template.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        else  {
            MobileAds.initialize(context) {
                val adLoader: AdLoader =
                    AdLoader.Builder(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                        .forNativeAd { nativeAd -> 
                            //                        if (isDestroyed) {
                            //                          nativeAd.destroy()
                            //                            return
                            //                        }
                            val styles = NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build()
                            val template =
                                holder.itemView.findViewById<TemplateView>(R.id.my_template)
                            template.setStyles(styles)
                            template.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            template.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
                        }
                        .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                                
                            }
                        })
                        .withNativeAdOptions(
                            NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                                .build()
                        )
                        .build()
                adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return parentList.size
    }   
}
```

PEOPLENEARBY FRAGMENT CODE FOR NESTED RECYCLER VIEW:

```
private suspend fun loopArray(peoplnearbylists:MutableList<List<PeopleNearByModelClass>>, lastarraysize: JSONArray) {
    val lastArrayList = lastarraysize

    val totalSize = peoplnearbylists.size

    val rowLists = peoplnearbylists
    //  val totalsize = peoplnearbylists.size

    for (index in 0 until totalSize) {
        val rowList = rowLists[index]
        val maxUsers = minOf(rowList.size, 12) // Update the maximum number of users per row
        val uniqueUserSet = HashSet<String>() // Track unique user names

        val peopleList = mutableListOf<Peoples>()
        for (i in 0 until maxUsers step 12) {
            val person1 = rowList[i]
            val person2 = rowList[i + 1]
            val person3 = rowList[i + 2]
            val person4 = rowList[i + 3]
            val person5 = rowList[i + 4]
            val person6 = rowList[i + 5]
            val person7 = rowList[i + 6]
            val person8 = rowList[i + 7]
            val person9 = rowList[i + 8]
            val person10 = rowList[i + 9]
            val person11 = rowList[i + 10]
            val person12 = rowList[i + 11]
            peopleList.add(
                Peoples(
                    title1 = person1.userName,
                    img1 = person1.userImage,
                    userid1 = person1.userID,
                    title2 = person2.userName,
                    img2 = person2.userImage,
                    userid2 = person2.userID,
                    title3 = person3.userName,
                    img3 = person3.userImage,
                    userid3 = person3.userID,
                    title4 = person4.userName,
                    img4 = person4.userImage,
                    userid4 = person4.userID,
                    title5 = person5.userName,
                    img5 = person5.userImage,
                    userid5 = person5.userID,
                    title6 = person6.userName,
                    img6 = person6.userImage,
                    userid6 = person6.userID,
                    title7 = person7.userName,
                    img7 = person7.userImage,
                    userid7 = person7.userID,
                    title8 = person8.userName,
                    img8 = person8.userImage,
                    userid8 = person8.userID,
                    title9 = person9.userName,
                    img9 = person9.userImage,
                    userid9 = person9.userID,
                    title10 = person10.userName,
                    img10 = person10.userImage,
                    userid10 = person10.userID,
                    title11 = person11.userName,
                    img11 = person11.userImage,
                    userid11 = person11.userID,
                    title12 = person12.userName,
                    img12 = person12.userImage,
                    userid12 = person12.userID
                )
            )
        }

        mParentList.add(Parent("", peopleList))

    }

    mAdapter = ParentAdapter(requireContext(), mParentList, totalSize)

    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }
}
```

A

Comment: have you tried using Jetpack Navigation (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#0) ?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using viewbinding. Your code is very hard to follow: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding. Including in your viewholders and wherever you see a lot of lines of code consider making collections and going through them via a for loop and calling a function. Egg:

```
onBindViewHolder(...){
 ....
  setTitileText(listOf(holder.title1,holder.title2 ...),listOf(title1,titel2...))
 ....
}
....
fun setTitileText(ar : List<View>,titles :List<String>){
     for (index in 0 until ar.size){
         if(titles.size <= index) continue   
         index = if (title1.length>10) title1.substring(0,10)+"..."else title1
     }
}
```

As for how to intercept onBackPressed events you need to add in your parent activity, on `onCreate()` a callback using `onBackPresedDispatcher`

```
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this){
        //todo: see which fragment is being shown and make the coresponding transactions
        if(myFragment.isShown) ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...  I have added backpressed callback event.   requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                Log.d("ProfileViewPeople", "callback()")
            }
        })  This method not called in logs.

Comment: add it in your fragments too and call `requireActivity.onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`